# couch db finding data without views

Tags: database, nosql, couchdb

I want to know is there any way in Couch DB HTTP API to query database without VIEWS ? We can GET all documents / document with specific id but what if we want to query database with key other then ID, without using VIEWS ?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot query a CouchDB database by anything other than primary key (ID) without using views. In CouchDB world, views are queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the data from CouchDB without views using HTTP API of couchDB.

http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API

Documents stored in a CouchDB have a DocID. DocIDs are case-sensitive string identifiers that uniquely identify a document. Two documents cannot have the same identifier in the same database, they are considered the same document.

```
http://localhost:5984/test/some_doc_id
http://localhost:5984/test/another_doc_id
http://localhost:5984/test/BA1F48C5418E4E68E5183D5BD1F06476
```